# How to assign FTP URL

Tags: visual-studio, url, amazon-ec2, ftp

I got an AMI of Windows Server 2012 running on Amazon, and use it as website container for all my web sites. I recently created an app in WinForms, I need to publish it. In the moment that I use the publish option it asks for an FTP site. I already use **FileZilla Server**. I created an user and account. The matter here is that it asks for an FTP URL (ftp.example.com) and I only got (http://example.com). I try to do this with IIS but only can do it with HTTP.  **How can I create an FTP URL for the site that will contains my ClickOnce app ?**.

Answer (score 1):

Check *Public DNS* column on *Instances* page of Amazon EC2 console.

Note that the public DNS may change when the instance is restarted.

So your FTP URL would be like:
`ftp://ec2-45-123-87-128.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com/`

*Though, you need to configure the instance firewall to allow the FTP traffic, what is not easy in general. But that's out of scope of your question.*

Comment: Is there any way i can assing a custom ftp url for a specific domain ? like ftp://demo.iubix.net